# jdbc update is updating zero rows without any runtime exception

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Team,
I have a need to execute update query multiple times based on date field, to avoid multiple database call I am trying to club multiple records where same date is updated and then call them using IN clause.

I have map "Map<Date, StringBuilder> data" which contains date and comma separated ID's which needs to be updated.

```
final String FOO_SQL_UPDATE_QUERY = "update foo_table set foo_ts = ? where foo_id in (?);";
data.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
                jdbcTemplate.update(FOO_SQL_UPDATE_QUERY, e.getKey(),
                        e.getValue());
            });
```

somehow this won't throw any error and updates 0 rows and here foo_ts is timestamp and foo_id is big int in postgres DB.

I tried below option as well which works for one id but then with multiple id's in IN clause it is failing, since comma separated id's will go as string instead of long.

```
Map.Entry<Date, StringBuilder> entry = iterator.next();
            int[] types = {Types.DATE, Types.BIGINT};
            Object[] params = {entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()};
            int i= jdbcTemplate.update(FOO_SQL_UPDATE_QUERY,params,types );
```

Please advise how can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you,

```
    JdbcTemplate template = null;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Map<Date, StringBuilder> exampleMap = new HashMap<>();
    exampleMap.put(new Date(), new StringBuilder().append("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7"));

    String sql = "update foo_table set foo_ts = ? where foo_id in (?);";

    exampleMap.forEach((date, stringBuilder) -> {

        Stream<String> streamOfIds = Stream.of(stringBuilder.toString().split(",", -1));

        List<Object> variables = streamOfIds.map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());

        variables.add(0, format.format(date));

        int[] types = new int[variables.size()];
        Arrays.fill(types, Types.INTEGER);
        types[0] = Types.DATE;

        System.out.println(variables);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(types));

        int row = template.update(sql, variables.toArray(), types);

    });
```

System.out:

```
[2021-11-17, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  
[91, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]   //91 is Types.Date, 4 is Types.Integer
```

Comment: Thanks @SMA, getting DataIntegrity Violation exception with this approach when there are multiple ID's  (in this case there were 2 ids).      
 org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [update foo_table set foo_ts = ? where foo_id in (?);]; The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.                                     Looks like with types field it is matching with number of columns replacing the sql placeholder.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate with below implementation.   final String FOO_SQL_UPDATE_QUERY = "update foo_table set foo_ts = :foots where foo_id in (:fooIds);";  data.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
IntStream streamOfIds = Stream.of(e.getValue().substring(1).toString().split(",", -1)).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt);  List<Integer> variables = streamOfIds.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());  MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

Comment: namedParameters.addValue("fooIds", e.getValue().substring(1));
  namedParameters.addValue("foots", e.getKey());
  int i= namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(FOO_SQL_UPDATE_QUERY, namedParameters); });

Comment: ok, so your issue is fixed? Great